# Wrong html <meta and <link tags indentation in vim

Tags: html, vim, indentation

When I do `gg=G`, almost everything get indented correctly, except `<meta` tag and `<link` tag when there is no `/` in before `>` like this `/>`.

here is a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <meta name="description" content="">
                        <br>

                        <meta name="keywords" content="">
                            <meta name="author" content="">

                                <title>
                                    Site Title
                                </title>
                                <!-- CSS -->

                                <link href="css/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                    <link href="css/cos.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/ie8.js"></script><![endif]-->
                                        <script src="../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
                                        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                                                                                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                                                                                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                                                                                    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                                                                                        <![endif]-->

                                                                                        <!-- Favicons -->
                                                                                        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
                                                                                            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

                                                                                                <script>

                                                                                                </script>

                                                                                            </head>
                                                                                            <body>


                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   </body>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               </html>
```

Here is what expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <br>

        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>
        Site Title
        </title>
        <!-- CSS -->

        <link href="css/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/cos.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/ie8.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="js/ie.js"></script>
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Favicons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

        <script>

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>


    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried everything I could find on the net, but still the same.
I'm using VIM version 7.4.873. MacVim 7.4 (77) compiled by Homebrew.
here is my .vimrc file:

```
filetype plugin indent on

syntax on
set bg=dark                             "background=dark

set ic                                  "ignorecase
set hls                                 "hlsearch
set is                                  "incsearch
set scs                                 "smartcase
set gd                                  "gdefault

set ai                                  "autoindent
set si                                  "smartindent
set ci                                  "copyindent
set pi                                  "preserveindentd
set bs=2                                "backspace=indent,eol,start

set fenc=utf-8                          "fileencoding=utf-8
set enc=utf-8                           "encoding=utf-8

set ts=4                                "tabstop=4
set sts=0                               "softtabstop=0
set sw=4                                "shiftwidth=4
set noet                                "noexpandtab

"set sm                                 "showmatch
set ru                                  "ruler
set nu                                  "number
set rnu                                 "relativenumber
set wrap                                "wrap
set ch=1                                "cmdheight=1
set title                               "title
set ls=2                                "laststatus=always
set stl=%.50F%m\                        "statusline=F 
set stl+=\|\ 
set stl+=%p%%\ 
set stl+=\:\ %l/%L\ 
set stl+=\:\ %c\ 
set stl+=\:\ %v\ 
set stl+=%=
set stl+=%y
set stl+=[%{&fenc?&enc:&fenc}]
set stl+=[\#%n] 
set cul                                 "cursorline
set clipboard=unnamed

" Other settings
let g:PHP_vintage_case_default_indent = 1
```

No plugin or indent scripts.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you type `set ft?`, what does it show? On my Vim, on default configuration, `ft=xml` does what you get; `ft=html` does the right thing.

Comment: @Amadan I get `filetype=html`.

Comment: Hmm, no idea then. Maybe an old Vim? (Mine is 7.4, from 2013)

Comment: I don't know, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: You have `smartindent` off?

Comment: Hmm, maybe not default configuration. Try [vim-web-indent](https://github.com/lukaszb/vim-web-indent) plugin, see if it helps you.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, I tried in both cases, on and off, still the same.

Comment: @Amadan, I tried vim-web-indent. still the same.

Comment: Well, just close the tags ...

Comment: @VanLaser Only to satisfy a stubborn editor? That sounds like it doesn't really solve the problem, only hide it.

Comment: Vim is not stuborn, it offers the `equalprg` option ...

Comment: `<br>` in line 8 is making it invalid.

Comment: @JJoao With or without `<br>` in line 8, same results.

Comment: @VanLaser I tried equalprg with tidy (tidy-html5), but tidy has its own problems in VIM, e.g.: inserting new line after the closing tag of many tags, also putting comments in the same line with the closing tag of the tag that is just before the comment.

Comment: The idea is this: if an external, dedicated program doesn't do what you want, why do you expect that from Vim (which isn't dedicated to html)? In any case, nothing stops you finding, configuring or even writing an external program and hook it to Vim.

Comment: @VanLaser You missed the point! I'm trying to figure out why my VIM acting this way while -as it seems- other people's don't. Amadan stated that his/her VIM acts correctly. Sure thing if I have the time I'll spend it on hocking vim, but now I'm busy with both studying and working, and was hoping if someone could help.

Comment: You try using the syntastic package?  I had no issues in my VIM with this and indent set to 4 spaces...